# How can I get a directory listing of EXE & DLLs with ProductName and ProductVersion via powershell including all subfolders

Tags: powershell

I need to gather information about all DLL's and EXE files from a directory tree and ideally export them to a csv format.

The initial folder structure will always be:

```
C:\Folder Name\
```

however beyond that the structure may change for subfolders.

I attempted to modify the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332005/how-can-i-get-a-directory-listing-of-dlls-with-productname-and-productversion) however ran into issues with subfolders

```
dir c:\windows\*.dll | % {[System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo($_)} | % { $_.ProductName + ", " + $_.ProductVersion + ", " + $_.FileName} > test.log
```

The output file should include the same information as the above code but for all DLL and EXE files where the information is available, in all subfolders

How do I go about getting my result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Get-ChildItem` with `-Recurse` and multiple `-Include` filters:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Windows\*' -Recurse -Include *.dll,*.exe | % {[System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo($_)} | % { $_.ProductName + ", " + $_.ProductVersion + ", " + $_.FileName} > report.log
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$InPath    = 'C:\Folder Name'
$OutFile   = 'C:\OutPath\ProgInfo.csv'

Get-ChildItem -Path $InPath -File -Recurse | Where Extension -match '\.dll|\.exe' |
ForEach-Object {[PSCustomObject]@{
    'FileName' = $_.FullName
    'ProdName' = $_.VersionInfo.ProductName
    'Version'  = $_.VersionInfo.ProductVersion
}} | Export-Csv -Path $OutFile -NoTypeInformation
```

If you're just banging away at the console, you can shorten it somewhat with aliases:

```
gci 'C:\Folder Name' -af -s | ? Extension -match '\.dll|\.exe' |
% {[PSCustomObject]@{
    'FileName' = $_.FullName
    'ProdName' = $_.VersionInfo.ProductName
    'Version'  = $_.VersionInfo.ProductVersion
}} | Export-Csv 'C:\OutPath\ProgInfo.csv' -NoType
```

Comment: Thanks Keith, When running this I received an error. Will post the error monday to show what happened